# How can I know whether the value posted in c# reached PHP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webclient

I am a beginner in C#, I am creating a windows phone app in which login page requests validation from remote url's PHP file ,I can get the response from the PHP file but I dont know how to check ,Whether the value(Username,Password) is Posted to PHP file

**Program**

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var username = usernames .Text;
    var password = passwords .Password;

    var postMessage = new StringContent(string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", username, password), Encoding.UTF8 , "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var response = await (new HttpClient()).PostAsync("http://xxx.xxxx.xxx/xxx.php", postMessage);
}
```

I want to Know how to post and receive value from c# to php

Comment: not sure about c# but in PHP u can get them as $_POST["username"] or $_GET["username"] if the http verb used as POST or GET.

Comment: I'm confident that both aspects of your question have been covered here before, but I don't understand what the problem is you're having specifically.

Comment: I cant get the posted value from c# in PHP it returns null